# Create a Dynamic Query into a Temp table instead of hard coding union statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have hardcoded a bunch of union statements to create a row for each region, for each month for each fiscal year (the example is just for the fiscal year 2017). Instead of all these lines of code, I would really like to 'build a loop' that dynamically creates the temp table instead of the hundreds of lines of code and union statements.

*****Update code from Gordon's proposed solution

```
SELECT dt.fulldate AS trade_month, 
       t.trade_gy  AS trade_gy, 
       r.dvsregion_id, 
       r.dvsregion_name 
FROM   dimdate dt 
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('2017'), 
                          ('2018')) AS t(trade_gy) 
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('1', 
                  'Midwest'), 
                          ('2', 
                  'Northeast')) as r(dvsregion_id, dvsregion_name) 
WHERE  Year(dt.fulldate) >= 2012 
       AND dt.fulldate = dt.firstofmonthdate 
       AND dt.fulldate IN (SELECT p.fulldate 
                           FROM   dimdate p 
                           WHERE  ( Year(p.fulldate) ) >= 2012 
                                  AND p.lastdayofgasyear <= '2018-03-31') 
ORDER  BY trade_gy ASC, 
          trade_month ASC
```

- **Start date** would be 1-1-2012*
- **End date** changes for each fiscal year.
- Our fiscal year ends on March 31st (2017 ends 3-31-18, and so on).
- Fiscal years includes 2017 - 2023
- Regions: Midwest, Northeast, Western, Canada

Any suggestions or links that will help me is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Sample of the code for the Fiscal year 2017. All other years are the same format, except I update **p.LastDayofGasYear <= '3-31-2018')** for each fiscal year.

```
 Select *
into #Regions
From (
--Create regions temp table for GY 2017
select
dt.FullDate as trade_month ,
'2017' as trade_gy,
'1' as dvsregion_id, 
'Midwest' as dvsregion_name
from dimDate dt
where  (year(dt.FullDate)) >= 2012  
and dt.FullDate = dt.FirstOfMonthDate
and dt.FullDate IN (
Select p.FullDate
from dimDate p
where (year(p.FullDate)) >= 2012 and p.LastDayofGasYear <= '3-31-2018')
Union
select
dt.FullDate as trade_month ,
'2017' as trade_gy,
'2' as dvsregion_id, 
'Northeast' as dvsregion_name
from dimDate dt
where  (year(dt.FullDate)) >= 2012  
and dt.FullDate = dt.FirstOfMonthDate
and dt.FullDate IN (
Select p.FullDate
from dimDate p
where (year(p.FullDate)) >= 2012 and p.LastDayofGasYear <= '3-31-2018')
Union
select
dt.FullDate as trade_month ,
'2017' as trade_gy,
'3' as dvsregion_id, 
'Western' as dvsregion_name
from dimDate dt
where  (year(dt.FullDate)) >= 2012  
and dt.FullDate = dt.FirstOfMonthDate
and dt.FullDate IN (
Select p.FullDate
from dimDate p
where (year(p.FullDate)) >= 2012 and p.LastDayofGasYear <= '3-31-2018')
Union
select
dt.FullDate as trade_month ,
'2017' as trade_gy,
'5' as dvsregion_id, 
'Canada' as dvsregion_name
from dimDate dt
where  (year(dt.FullDate)) >= 2012  
and dt.FullDate = dt.FirstOfMonthDate
and dt.FullDate IN (
Select p.FullDate
from dimDate p
where (year(p.FullDate)) >= 2012 and p.LastDayofGasYear <= '3-31-2018')
```

[End Results will look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8HnK.png)

Comment: In a previous question you mentioned that you have a regions table. So why do you think you need to hardcode these values in your query? It takes time and work to start thinking in terms of sets - you have quite a bit of that ahead of you. And generally speaking, the use of hard-coded IDs is a big red flag that suggests you need to revisit your approach.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I need to take a different approach. I do have a Regions table and dimDate table I can use. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want `cross join`s on constant values:

```
select dt.FullDate as trade_month ,
       t.trade_gy as trade_gy,
       r.dvsregion_id, 
       r.dvsregion_name
from dimDate dt cross join
     (values ('2017', '2018', . . .) as t(trade_gy) cross join
     (values ('1', 'Midwest'),
             ('2', 'Northeast'),
             . . .
     ) r(dvsregion_id, dvsregion_name)
where year(dt.FullDate)) >= 2012 and
      dt.FullDate = dt.FirstOfMonthDate and
      dt.FullDate in (Select p.FullDate
                      from dimDate p
                      where (year(p.FullDate)) >= 2012 and p.LastDayofGasYear <= '2018-03-31'
                     );
```

I'm no sure if I fully follow all the logic in your quite complex query, but I think it can be structured like this.

Comment: I will take a look at this as soon as I am back in the office this morning. Thank you !

Comment: Hello,

Sorry for the delayed response, but got busy yesterday.

I was able to modify this a bit to get it to work and it is close. 

Fiscal Year 2017 ends on '2018-03-31', but fiscal year for 2018 ends on '2019-3-01'.

This is true for all the fiscal years. I am not sure how to modify the WHERE statement to adjust to increment for each fiscal year. 

I will update my original question to show the updates to your code you suggested. I am limited on the number of characters in the comment area. 

thanks

Comment: @Brent . . . I have no idea where the fiscal year is being used in the `where` clause.

Comment: Sorry about that:

AND p.lastdayofgasyear <= '2018-03-31')

This is the end of fiscal year 2017

Comment: I am going to break this query up into a couple of different temp tables to make it easier. Your answer above provides what I needed for the first temp table. Thank you!!

Comment: @Brent . . . You can probably include that as an additional column in one of the `values()` table constructors . . . probably with the year.